# Images with Mouseover Hover: Transparent Boxes Not Same Size as Image

Tags: html, css, image, transparency, boxsizer

I have some code that added a hover effect of a transparent box over my images with text overlay, however the transparent boxes are not snapping to the size of the images. The transparent boxes seem to be either too small (leaving the top and bottom of the image below to not go transparent) or far too large (causing my page to fall out of alignment entirely). It may be a box-sizing issue? I think I have it set up so that it should automatically become 100% the size of the image, but I may be missing something.

Link to my site: http://jchambliss.aisites.com/imd311/portfolio/sites.html

Necessary code is included here:

```css
#preview {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Web Design Projects */
.sitesAds {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesAds:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesTokyo {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesTokyo:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesMobile {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesMobile:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesRoux {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesRoux:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amita|Encode+Sans+Expanded|Leckerli+One|Merienda+One|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div>

<table>
<tr>
   <td><a href="ads.html"><div class="sitesAds"><img src="images/ads.jpg" id="preview" alt="Banner Ads"/>
    <h3 id="text">Banner Ads</h3></div></a>
   </td>
   <td><a href="tokyo.html"><div class="sitesTokyo"><img src="images/tokyo.jpg" id="preview" alt="One Page Ad Site: Tokyo, Japan"/>
    <h3 id="text">One Page Ad Site: Tokyo, Japan</h3></div></a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a href="mobile.html"><div class="sitesMobile"><img src="images/mobile.jpg" id="preview" alt="Mobile App: Tea Shoppe"/>
    <h3 id="text">Mobile App: Tea Shoppe</h3></div></a>
   </td>
   <td><a href="roux.html"><div class="sitesRoux"><img src="images/roux.jpg" id="preview" alt="Roux Academy of Art, Media, and Design"/>
    <h3 id="text">Roux Academy of Art, Media, and Design</h3></div></a>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`width: 100%`** on `img` instead of `max-width` & remove `padding: 0` from `#text`

> make sure you should use unique `id`s for each `h3` element as id cannot be the same on a single page

Example:

```
.sitesTokyo img {
  width: 100%;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* For vertical centering */
  justify-content: center; /* For horizontal centering */
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0; /* Remove padding */
  padding: 0; /* Remove margin */
}
```

Also have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
#preview {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Web Design Projects */
.sitesAds {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesAds:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesTokyo {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesTokyo:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesMobile {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesMobile:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}

.sitesRoux {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sitesRoux:hover #text {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 60px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #663366;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amita|Encode+Sans+Expanded|Leckerli+One|Merienda+One|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div>

<table>
<tr>
   <td><a href="ads.html"><div class="sitesAds"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="preview" alt="Banner Ads"/>
    <h3 id="text">Banner Ads</h3></div></a>
   </td>
   <td><a href="tokyo.html"><div class="sitesTokyo"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="preview" alt="One Page Ad Site: Tokyo, Japan"/>
    <h3 id="text">One Page Ad Site: Tokyo, Japan</h3></div></a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a href="mobile.html"><div class="sitesMobile"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="preview" alt="Mobile App: Tea Shoppe"/>
    <h3 id="text">Mobile App: Tea Shoppe</h3></div></a>
   </td>
   <td><a href="roux.html"><div class="sitesRoux"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="preview" alt="Roux Academy of Art, Media, and Design"/>
    <h3 id="text">Roux Academy of Art, Media, and Design</h3></div></a>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you SO much! This absolutely worked! I've been staring at this code for a week now and had gotten so much closer to figuring out the issue, but was going "code-blind". This was a simple error and a simple correction. Thank you again very much!

Comment: Actually... this works fine in Dreamweaver, but when I upload the corrected code to the server, I'm still getting the same over-sized box results. I cleared my cookies but still having the issue. Would you kindly check my newly updated code?

Comment: @ChinoChinako You are still using `max-width: 100%` on your `img` tag. Use **`width: 100%`** instead. You'll be able to achieve it.

Comment: I updated my code to remove the max-width, padding, and margins as you specified in your comment, however now I am getting no transparency on hover at all. I added an additional DIV tag to add text below the images as well, but it doesn't have a class so I don't think this is the issue. Would you like me to update my code above?

Comment: I figured it out! I have mis-named my sections in my CSS and I forgot a semicolon after the width. Thank you for all your help. Consider this question answered and closed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your image size. The divs you hover over are bigger than the images. You have to set image width to 100%;

```
.sitesMobile img { width: 100%}
```